# Visual Studio isn't running the python file and gives me command not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm new to programming, I've started working on python few weeks ago and learned online, I already used VS Code to write some lines of code related to Django and created some backend with it for a website,
I've never noticed that I only used the files using the web browser, now I created a file and wrote the famous Print('Hello World') in it, I didn't use shell or anything but instead I the run code icon you have on the top in VS Code and got this error

[Running] python -u "/Users/montaser/Desktop/Coding_Bootcamp/python_stack/_python/python_fundamentals/tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
/bin/sh: python: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.013 seconds

how can I overcome this?

note that the file runs if I use the terminal (outside or inside of the VS code) and use the command (python3 hello_world.py)
I've seen a video of a guy running the file using the run code button in VS code so I"m not sure what I'm missing

Comment: If `python3` is the command that works to run Python code on your system, then you need to tell VS Code to use that command, rather than just `python`.

Comment: don't use that button. Use a launch configuration, read the VSC Python doc pages, part of it is selecting the Python interpreter to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not use *Code Runner* to execute scripts, use the official extension **Python**(`Run Python File`).

[image]

Follow [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) to get started.

If you want to use the execution method in the question, you need to add the python interpreter path to your machine's environment variable `path`.